# Can't get the objects collection in a Many-to-many relationship from database

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following hierarchy in Hibernate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "elements")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)

public abstract class Elements implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idelement")
    private Integer idElement;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "elementsCollection")
    private Collection<ElementsGroups> elementsGroupsCollection;

    .
    .
    More attributes, constructor and getter/setter
    .
    .
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "valves")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="idelement")
@XmlRootElement
public class Valves extends Elements {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "position")
    private int position;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private boolean status;

    .
    .
    More attributes, constructor and getter/setter
    .
    .
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "elementsgroups")
@XmlRootElement
public class ElementsGroups implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idgroup")
    private Integer idGroup;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name="joinelementsgroups", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idgroup")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idelement")})
    private Collection<Elements> elementsCollection;

    .
    .
    More attributes, constructor and getter/setter
    .
    .
}
```

The idea is having an "Elements" superclass to wrap a bunch elements of the system which share some charecteristics and functionality. These elements can be grouped in several groups. This is the database structure:

[image]

When I persist an object of the `Valve` subclass, and add it to one group, I can see the changes in the database. Something like this:

```
    SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    Session s = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();  
    Valve v1 = new Valve();
    Valve v2 = new Valve();
    s.save(v1);
    s.save(v2);
    tx.commit();

    tx = s.beginTransaction();
    LinkedList<Elements> valves = new LinkedList<>();
    valves.add(v1);
    valves.add(v2);
    ge.setElementsCollection(valves);

    s.save(ge);
    tx.commit();

//Database: OK
```

And when I get the `Valve` object, I can get the groups which the object belongs to, through its getter method. The problem appears when I try to get the `ElementsGroups` object, where I can get all its attributes, but `elementsCollection` is empty instead of containing the `Valve` added before:

```
    tx = s.beginTransaction();
    Valve v1 = (Valve)s.get(Valve.class, 3);
    for(ElementsGroups g : v1.getElementsGroupsCollection())
        System.out.println("Valve belongs to: " + g);

    ElementsGroups ge = (ElementsGroups)s.get(ElementsGroups.class, 1);
    System.out.println("Group number of elements: " + ge.getElementsCollection().size());

    tx.commit();
```

Output:

```
Valve belongs to: model.ElementsGroups[ idgroup=1 ]
Group number of elements: 0
```

I have similar relationships already implemented which don't show this problem, so I'm guessing the problem probably has to be related with the hierarchy of the classes, but I'm new to Hibernate and don't know if I'm missing something.

ps: Note that I droped several parts of the code to facilitate its reading, but I can add if necessary

Comment: ge.setElementsCollection(valves); - from where does teh ge come from? it seems to be created outside of the transaction?

Comment: Sorry @MaciejKowalski, it's inside of the transaction, I already edited this part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to populate the Valve entities with the ElementGroups entity so that both sides have the references to each other:

```
    tx = s.beginTransaction();
    LinkedList<Elements> valves = new LinkedList<>();

    Valve managedV1 = s.merge(v1);
    Valve managedV2 = s.merge(v2);

    valves.add(managedV1);
    valves.add(managedV2);

    managedV1.getElementsGroupsCollection().add(ge);
    managedV2.getElementsGroupsCollection().add(ge);

    ge.setElementsCollection(valves);

    s.save(ge);
    tx.commit();
```

Also i think you should merge the Valves first in the second transaction.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works when I persist the object in database, but when I retrieve the object once persisted, relationships are not included. How should I retrieve the object from database then? I still think I'm missing something 
In others many-to-many relationships implemented in the same application, I have only to retrieve the object with "Session.get()" method, but with this implementation the collection remains empty

Comment: If you want to have the relationship loaded as well then you have to use @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) on top of cascade. Just remember to add it only on one side of the relationsip.